# Windows 10 prevent delayed programs startup

Tags: windows, login

I have some apps mouse "driver", nvidia applet, virtuawin and a shell script to run under the Startup folder each time I log in. But only the first two are loaded on login, the Logitech G-HUB and the nvidia applet (which also runs as a service).

What drives me crazy is both virtualwin and the shell script are not running on logon. If I run it manually works fine, but I don't want to have to run it each time I boot.

As per google searches I also set StartupDelayInMSec to REG_DWORD 0:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Serialize
```

another related question: assuming the worst case scenario that this is not possible to fix, is there any third party tool that allow me to start programs on login?

thank you

Comment: Perhaps package up the drivers in question as services.  Look up package an app as a service

Comment: We need more info about the defined tasks, and what is the difference between the ones that start and the ones that don't. In addition, it's a bad idea to set the delay to zero, since tasks might fail if their context is not completely set up. Try instead to set this to 2 minutes.